# Explain the DateTime.Now design in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, oop

I have a question regarding the design of the Date object in the .Net framework, more specifically the Now property.

I know that Now is a property that is a Date type.  (This makes sense since I see the methods .AddHours(), AddYears(), etc)  If Now being a class(or struct) how does it return a value directly.

For example: How would I create a class or struct in C#/VB.net that would allow me to do the same without calling a property of Now?

(VB.Net)
Dim WeatherObject as new WeatherReporter()

If WeeatherReport had a property called TodaysWeather that was a class how could I then get a value like this

Dim PlainTextReport as string=WeeatherReport.TodaysWeather

To me it seems like you would have to call a another property off of TodaysWeather. But with the Datetime.Now example you don't.  Anyways, I know its an odd question. I was just trying to better understand how some of these objects are set up under the hood

Thanks for any light on the matter.

Here is an example of code referring to the above question.

```
Public Class WeatherReporter
    Shared ReadOnly Property TodaysWeather As DayWeather
        Get
            TodaysWeather = New DayWeather
            Return TodaysWeather.Current
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class DayWeather
    Public Property Current As String = "Sunny"
End Class
```

Now similar to the DateTime.Now object

How could one you the weather example like this

```
Dim TheForecast as string=WeatherReporter.TodaysWeather
```

It seems like it would require the following

```
Dim TheForecast as string=WeatherReporter.TodaysWeather.Current
```

I know its a confusing question, lol. thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` looks something like this in VB.net...

```
public structure DateTime

    ...other code...

    ''// `shared` makes this a class property, not an instance property.
    ''// This is what lets you say `DateTime.Now`
    public shared readonly property Now as DateTime
        get
            ... do some magic to return the current date/time ...
        end get
    end property

    ... other code ...

end class
```

or in C#:

```
public struct DateTime
{
    ... other code ...

    // `static` works like VB's `shared` here
    public static DateTime Now
    {
        get { /* do your magic to return the current date/time */ }
    }

    ... other code ...
}
```

Comment: Just to add because that's apparently his question: The importance here is the static Keyword (or shared in VB) which makes it a method/property of the Type, not of the Instance.

Answer (score 4):

Reflecting the source code it's evident that it's simply a property wrapper around a function.

```
public static DateTime Now
{
    get
    {
        return UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

You don't need to instantiate a DateTime object since the property is marked as `static`.

Comment: Nitpicking: that's actually a wrapper around a method call on the return value of another property.  :)  Principle's about the same, though.

Answer (score 2):

.NET properties are more than merely values - they encapsulate *getter* and *setter* methods around underlying values. That being the case, they can initialize objects before returning them. So, for example, `DateTime.Now` may be implemented like this (without attempting to find its actual implementation via Reflector or Reference Sources...):

```cs
public static DateTime Now
{
    get
    {
        var d = new DateTime() { .Kind = DateTimeKind.Local };
        // Logic to determine the current system time and set d to that value
        return d;
    }
}
```

(ref: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How would you in C#or VB.Net return a value from a class in a line of code without referencing a property? Is the Now object have a default property inside it?

Comment: "Now" is not an Object - it is a Property within the DateTime Class.

Comment: I should have made that more clear. Also, as @cHao points out below, the important bit about the `Now` property is that it is static. It instantiates the `DateTime` that it returns on demand, it doesn't require an existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's implemented as a static getter method. I believe what your looking for would look something like this in your WeatherReporter class:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property TodaysWeather As WeatherReporter
    Get
        Return New WeatherReporter(DateTime.Now)
    End Get
End Property
```

That assumes that your WeatherReporter class has a constructor that accepts a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now is a static/Shared property. You don't have to instantiate a new object (using `New DateTime()`) to call it.